# How to get component selector name inside Directive ? Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I was trying to get selector name inside Directive, I am not sure either is it possible or how to do it.

```
<my-component1 *myDir="Var"> </my-component1>
<my-component2 *myDir="Var"> </my-component2>
<my-component3 *myDir="Var"> </my-component3>
```

i am using same directive on multiple components like given above, now i need to get current component **selector** name inside Directive like below. Please someone tell me how to get selector name inside directive

```
@Directive({
  selector : '[myDir]

'
    })

    export class MyDirDirective {
       constructor (){
         this.currentSelector  = getCurrentComponentSelector;
       }
    }
     @Input() set myDir(value:any){
      if(this.currentSelector==='my-component1'){
          i will do some action, display or not decide
      }
    }
```

Comment: BTW, that code is a bit... **wrong**. There shouldn't be an if statement in a class. It should be in a method instead. Secondly, the `currentSelector` property will not be accessible since you're declaring it in the `constructor`, which will make it local.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ElementRef` and get the tag name

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  const selector = el.nativeElement.tagName;
}

ngOnInit() {
  const selector = this.el.nativeElement.tagName;
}
```

(I'm not sure it would work in the constructor, so test both methods)

Comment: I think that `nativeElement` is comment node here

Comment: i guess there is no such key or object (tagname) inside native element. i am getting UNDEFINED @trichetriche

Comment: @Munna  That's because `comment` doesn't have `tagName` property. Try `nodeName` instead

Comment: getting '#comment' in the console, not getting selector name.

Comment: @Munna You won't get selector name with this method

Comment: Thanks,  ended up like this <my-component1 *myDir="Var + ', my-component1' "> </my-component1>  , and then using split(',') converting array and checking condition :( temporary fix for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cleaner solution that will work with AOT and when you're outside of the component in question:

```
const components = [ MyComponent ];
/*
  ...
  Anything that can be injected into
*/
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  // Loop through each component
  components.forEach(element => {
    // Get its resolved factory
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(element);

    console.log('Factory:', factory);
    console.log('Selector:', factory.selector);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can't make it better if you don't say why you downvoted.

Comment: How does this get anything related to the element that the directive is attached to?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is correct, but when i go through templateRef entire response and i saw component selector from the below location. So i am using this as temporary solution. I hope this might help someone.

**this.templateRef['_def']['element']['template']['lastRenderRootNode']['element']['name'];**

```
   export class MyDirDirective {
       constructor (private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>){
            this.currentSelector = this.templateRef['_def']['element']['template']['lastRenderRootNode']['element']['name'];
       }
    }

  @Input() set myDir(value:any){
      if(this.currentSelector === value){
          i will do some action, display or not decide
      }
    }
```